# Class not included in the aar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, aar

I'm using Android Studio 1.0.1.

I managed to configure Android Library module in a project, so it's built into AAR.

My problem is that the AAR archive does not have my class inside. When I check `MyProject/MyModule/build/intermediates/classes/debug/my/package/mymodule` I can see my class compiled: `MyClass.class`

But when I enter to AAR (or unpack it), the very same directory (I mean the `my/package/mymodule` in `classes.jar` inside of the AAR file) contains only one file: `BuildConfig.class`

Why isn't my class included in the AAR?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

maybe it has to do with the proguard configuration i had the same problem, i resolved it by adding a rule in the proguard-rules file. here is exactly what i did:

- adding rule `-keep public class my.package.** { public *;}` proguard-rules.pro file
- run `gradlew assemble` on terminal

after that you will find your aar file in `youModule/build/outputs/aar/` directory

Hope this help

Comment: You are the best

Answer (score 0):

I was messing around with plugins and in my case (a Kotlin library) I removed by accident too many of them. If your `*.aar` is *empty* too, make sure you've got at lease these two set:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    id("kotlin-android") // <-- this one was missing
}
```